# Other apps can add extensions to Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extensions

The following popup came up in Chrome today. From what it's saying, it seems like other apps have the ability to add extensions directly to Chrome. Is this correct? And if so, how is this not a huge gaping security concern for Google?  Or did I somehow unknowingly granted Adobe this permission?

[image]

Comment: It seems that Adobe is using some dodgy hack to get it installed. You certainly are not alone - [ghacks](http://www.ghacks.net/2017/01/11/warning-latest-adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-installs-chrome-extension/). This doesn't answer your question of how though...

Comment: Chrome was specifically designed to allow third party extensions, as does Internet Explorer, Firefox, and others. This is nothing new. It allows third party applications to add functionality to the browser. Unfortunately not all such extensions are well written and some are malicious. You either trust the application or disallow the extension. The dialog is giving the choice.

Comment: See http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/01/adobe-angers-chrome-users-by-bundling-browser-plugin-with-security-update/ . If this annoys you, uninstall Adobe Flash (I find most sites use HTML5 if Flash is not present.)

Comment: @LMiller7: I'm aware of extensions - I use plenty all the time.  What bothers me is that I never explicitly installed this one.  I was unaware that unrelated 3rd party installers (e.g. Adobe's "Reader" installer) were allowed to install extensions into Chrome.  The only way I was aware that they could be installed was explicitly by the user.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Good article, thanks for the link.  I don't think uninstalling Flash would help though, would it?  This is related to Adobe Reader, right?

Comment: Oops... I stand corrected. BTW, there are alternate, faster and perhaps safer, readers than Acrobat, e.g. Sumatra.

Comment: Is this really a "gaping security hole" if it pops up an alert and requires you to select "Enable extension" to allow it to complete? My guess is that this happened because of the Adobe Reader/Acrobat update that came out this week.

Comment: @Barmar: You're right, "gaping" may be an exaggeration, since the extension is disabled until the user clicks "Enable". My concern wasn't that it was automatically enabled, but rather that it got installed in the first place. Imagine if e.g. MS Windows allowed random computers on a network to install any programs on each others' PCs without their knowledge or consent, as long as those apps required accepting a dialog box before doing anything. I would still consider that a security issue, despite the dialog safety-net. Especially if--as in this case--the indicated default action is "Enable".